# What tools are available to edit/create AVM2 bytecode?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bytecode, avm2

I'd like to generate some bytecode for the Flash 10 AVM2 directly, i.e. without AS3. An assembler that produced a SWF file would be ideal.

Does this exist? If not, what's the easiest way to get from assembler → abc → SWF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [As3c](http://code.google.com/p/as3c/) is what I'm looking for:

> As3c is a bytecode compiler for the AVM2 written in C#.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if that's what you want but Haxe is opensource. Haxe has also a library that can produce bytecode from Haxe code.

Comment: haXe’s format.abc is close what I’m looking for, but I’d like to be able to write code directly in assembly, not haXe code that generates assembly.

If I can’t find a better option, this is probably what I’ll use; the haXe library looks like it’s very well done.